# JavaFX, TableView and the font color of the selected row

Tags: javafx, tableview

I get TableView like this:

```
TableView tableView = (TableView) ((AnchorPane) node).getChildren().get(0);
```

fill it with data like

```
tableView.setItems(FXCollections.observableList(vehicles));
```

this part is Ok. However, I'd like to change font properties of the currently row in the tableView and I cannot figure how to do it

I do not want to set `tableView.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);` as I want to display selection for the whole row, and not for a single cell

I tried to apply some css styles on TableRow and on Tabliew but without any success.

Is there any way to change font properties for the currently selected row in TableView?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tableview css styling is subtle and complicated.

*Solution*

Go to the source for the default JavaFX controls css and copy all of the `.table-view` sections which have a `:selected` psuedo-class into your own user stylesheet.

Remove the default attribute setting rules from each css selector section you copied and replace them with the css you want to apply for your selected rows.

As there of lots of `:selected` rules you might have to copy the same attribute settings in a few places (similarly to how the default attribute values are defined).

*Background Resources*

The default stylesheets for respective versions are:

- JavaFX 2.2 => [caspian.css](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/2.2/master/rt/raw-file/tip/javafx-ui-controls/src/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/caspian/caspian.css)
- Java 8 => [modena.css](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/tip/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css)

Consult the [css reference guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) and [css tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/css_tutorial/jfxpub-css_tutorial.htm) if your are confused.

*Quick Color Change Fix*

Note that if all you need is to set the fill color for the selection bar text, you can override the default constant color with your own constant using a single statement:

```
.root { -fx-selection-bar-text: firebrick; }
```

Just substitute whatever color you want for firebrick.  Similarly `-fx-selection-bar: midnightblue;` can be used to change the color of the background of the text.

Comment: Thanks jewelsea, your idea to use -fx-selection-bar-text and -fx-selection-bar has solved my problem

Comment: however if you use custom cellfactory and modify tablecell css you need to re-assign styles for that tablecell too (by some unknow resons)

Comment: for example for tablecell modified in tablecellfactory to display the same selection bar I did as :

Comment: .vGreen{
    -fx-background-color: darkseagreen;
    -fx-border-color: transparent -fx-table-cell-border-color -fx-table-cell-border-color -fx-table-cell-border-color;
}

Comment: and added these styles to container of tableview - #mainAnchorPane {
    -fx-selection-bar-text: white;
}

#mainAnchorPane .table-view:focused .table-row-cell:filled:selected .table-cell {
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-selection-bar-text;
    -fx-background-color: -fx-selection-bar;
}

Comment: @jewelsea, After struggling with JavaFX CSS for a long time, I finally took your advice: "Go to the source...". This is a must, and the only way to deal with JavaFX's intricacies and deviations from CSS proper. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This CSS Rule can be effective:

```
 #mytable .table-cell {
    -fx-text-fill:red ;
    -fx-border-color: none;
 }

  #mytable .table-cell:hover {
    -fx-text-fill: rgb(103,183,89) ;
    -fx-border-color: none;
 }
```